# crystral report decimal showing as ######

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have created an win forms application in visual studio 2010.in that i am showing a bill report using crystal report.

The problem i am facing is if the amount is greater than 900000 then it is showing as #######.

please help me to correct this.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to increase the width of the Crystal Report field.

If the length of the number exceeds the width of the Crystal Report field then the number is displayed as a series of `#`